# Store results data from api with enum

Tags: swift, enums

Hi I learn iOS development from Big Nerd Ranch book, I learn how to process a data from the web following the book guide. now I want to implement it in my own app, but since the book only show how to handle image data. I want to process the data not only image but also a string data which is a title from my model, I already try make the enum turn into a generic so it can return any type. this is my code

This is enum before I change into a generic

```
enum ImagesResult {
    case success(UIImage)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

this is enum after I change into generic

```
enum Results<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

this is the fetchImageData function

```
    func fetchDataResult(for video: Video, completion: @escaping (Results<Any>) -> ()) {
        guard let videoKey = video.videoID else {
            preconditionFailure("Video expected to have a video id")
        }

        if let image = imageStore.image(forKey: videoKey) {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success(image))
            }
            return
        }

        guard let videoURL = video.url else {
            preconditionFailure("Video expected to have video url")
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: videoURL)

        let task = sessions.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            let result = self.processImageRequest(data: data, error: error)

            if case let .success(image) = result {
                self.imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: videoKey)
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func processDataRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Results<Any> {

        guard
            let imageData = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                if data == nil {
                    return .failure(error!)
                } else {
                    return .failure(ThumbnailError.thumbnailCreationError)
                }
            }
        return .success(image)
    }
```

how I can add string and image to passed in into text label later after the session data task that already store in result constant

Answer (score 2):

A enum `Result` already exists,

> A value that represents either a success or a failure, including an associated value in each case.

You can create your own error enum to match all your error cases like this:

```
enum MyErrorEnum: Error {
    case myerror1
    case myerror2(String)
    
    var errorDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .myerror1:
            return "Error: Error 1 description."
        case .myerror2(let error):
            return error
        }
    }
}
```

And the result in your completion handler would be:

```
completion: @escaping (Result<(UIImage, String), MyErrorEnum>)
```

In order for you to return an image and a title

Comment: sorry my question is not clear I already edit my question, what I mean is how I can add string and image to passed in into text label later after the session data task that already store in result constant